# How do i fix Capacitor Web Settings error?

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, capacitor

[image]

Hello i am trying to build my capacitor 3 project. It works on iOS just fine but in Android version i am getting errors about WebSettings as it is seen on attached photo.

I am pretty sure it's a Webview problem but i didnt find a solution online.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.myproject.mobile;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;
import com.getcapacitor.community.fcm.FCMPlugin;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         // Initializes the Bridge
        this.init(savedInstanceState, new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {{
        // Additional plugins you've installed go here
        **add(com.getcapacitor.community.facebooklogin.FacebookLogin.class);
        add(com.getcapacitor.community.fcm.FCMPlugin.class);**
      }});
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rovespier.mobile" android:versionName="1.0.19" android:versionCode="10019">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
        
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name="com.rovespier.mobile.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

That should be a warning, your app should still build unless you have enabled some setting to not build if there are warnings.

You can update to capacitor 4, that line of code was removed.
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/4-0